# Regularization Problem and Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space

Tags: machine-learning, regularization, kernel-smoothing, splines

The following shows part of the page 169 of **The Element of Statistical Learning** that I want to make clear.

> We have
> $$\min_{f \in \mathcal H_K}[\sum_{i = 1}^NL(y_i, f(x_i)) + \lambda\Vert f\Vert_{\mathcal H_K}^2].$$
> It can be shown (see Exercise 5.15) that the solution is finite-dimensional, and has the form
> $$g(x) = \sum_{i  = 1}^N\alpha_i K(x, x_i).$$

I have solved the given exercise (5.15 (a) to (d)). For reference, the exercise 5.15 (d) is as follows:

> **Exercise 5.15(d)** : Suppose $\tilde g(x) = g(x) + \rho(x)$ with $\rho \in \mathcal H_K$ and orthogonal in $\mathcal H_K$ to each of $K(x, x_i), \forall i=1,...,N$. Show that
> $$\sum_{i = 1}^N L(y_i, \tilde g(x_i)) + J(\tilde g) \ge \sum_{i = 1}^N L(y_i, g(x_i)) + J(g)$$
> with equality iff $\rho = 0$.

Now, I guess it remains to show that every $f \in \mathcal H_K$ can be (uniquely?) decomposed as $f = g + \rho$, which is not sure for now. If this makes sense, then everything is clear. But, I'm stuck to whether my hypothesis is true and (if so) how I can show this.

I first tried to show there exists a Hilbert space, say, $\mathcal G$ whose basis consists of $\{K(\cdot, x_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ so that $g \in \mathcal G$ and $\rho \bot K(\cdot, x_i)$ for all $i=1,...,N$. But, I'm not certain about whether each of $\{K(\cdot, x_i)\}_{i=1}^N$ is linearly independent.

Any comments about this problem (or any uncertainties) would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of the [orthogonal decomposition theorem](https://planetmath.org/orthogonaldecompositiontheorem) for Hilbert spaces which says that for any Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and any closed subspace $A$ we have
$$\mathcal{H} = A \oplus A^\perp$$
where $A^\perp$ is the orthogonal complement of $A$, ie
$$A^\perp = \{h \in \mathcal{H}: \langle x, h\rangle = 0 \; \forall x \in A\}$$

By taking $A = \text{span}\{K(\cdot,x_i): i=1,\dots, N\}$ and noting that it is closed ([every finite-dimensional subspace of a normed space is closed](https://planetmath.org/everyfinitedimensionalsubspaceofanormedspaceisclosed)) the result follows. Both these results are very well known and can be found in most functional analysis textbooks.

Comment: I see, I was just focusing on something unimportant. Thank you.